# Return and show more than one parameter

Tags: java, android

Im new in java and I would like how to return and show more than one value.

this is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void updatePressureValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    if (mPressureCals == null) 
        return;
     double pressure = SensorTagData.extractBarometer(characteristic, mPressureCals);
     double temp = SensorTagData.extractBarTemperature(characteristic, mPressureCals);

    mTemperature.setText(String.format("%.1f\u00B0C", temp));
    mPressure.setText(String.format("%.2f", pressure));
}

private void updateAccelerometerValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic ){

    double accelerometerx = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometerx);
    double accelerometery = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometery);
    double accelerometerz = SensorTagData.extractAccelerometer(characteristic, mAccelerometerz);

    mAccelerometerx.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometerx));
    mAccelerometery.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometery));
    mAccelerometerz.setText(String.format("%.4f", accelerometerz));
}
}
```

**SensorData.java**

```
public class SensorData {

public static double extractHumAmbientTemperature(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
    int rawT = shortSignedAtOffset(c, 0);

    return -46.85 + 175.72/65536 *(double)rawT;
}

public static double extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {

    Integer x = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
    Integer y = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 1);
    Integer z = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 2) * -1;

    double scaledX = x / 64.0;
    double scaledY = y / 64.0;
    double scaledZ = z / 64.0;

    return scaledX; scaledY; scaledZ ;
}
```

I took the code from the internet and only the value of a sensor is displayed, I want to add the accelerometer but nose how. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Just make a class that holds what you want and return it. Seriously, first hit on Google for "return more than one value java" explains it. Did you even try to solve your problem yourself?

Comment: You could extend Object to do what you want, or, if it more generic in the values you want to pass back, consider just an array of ints.  In fact, this is what Android does for sensor data: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return an array...

```
public static double[] extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {

    Integer x = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
    Integer y = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 1);
    Integer z = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 2) * -1;

    double scaledX = x / 64.0;
    double scaledY = y / 64.0;
    double scaledZ = z / 64.0;

    return new double[] {scaledX, scaledY, scaledZ};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no tuple in Java which would ostensibly allow you to do this easily. Coupled with that, there is no pass by reference for function parameters.

The normal way to do this in Java is to create a class containing fields pertinent to your return values and return an instance of that class. This is a deliberate language design choice: returning a class instance tends to produce good maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

make a list of doubles and return it

```
    public class SensorData {

    public static double extractHumAmbientTemperature(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
     int rawT = shortSignedAtOffset(c, 0);

     return -46.85 + 175.72/65536 *(double)rawT;
    }

   public static List<Double> extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {

       Integer x = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 0);
       Integer y = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 1);
       Integer z = c.getIntValue(FORMAT_SINT8, 2) * -1;

       double scaledX = x / 64.0;
       double scaledY = y / 64.0;
       double scaledZ = z / 64.0;
       List<Double> list=new ArrayList<Double>();
       list.add(scaledX);
       list.add(scaledY);
       list.add(scaledZ);
       return list ;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with that you want to return:

```
public class myScaleData {
    public double scaledX,scaledY,scaledZ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object with the parameters you need:

[toutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try [javatuples](http://www.javatuples.org/) it's much more easier than making a class every time you gonna return multiple values, Example :

```
public static Triplet<Double,Double,Double> extractAccelerometer(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
    ...
    return new Triplet<Double,Double,Double>(scaledX,scaledY,scaledZ);
}
```

[visit javatuples website for more info](http://www.javatuples.org/)